# Filtering on annotations with max date in Django

Tags: django, django-filter

I have 3 models in Django-project:

```
class Hardware(models.Model):
    inventory_number = models.IntegerField(unique=True,)

class Subdivision(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,)

class Relocation(models.Model):
    hardware = models.ForeignKey('Hardware',)
    subdivision = models.ForeignKey('Subdivision',)
    relocation_date = models.DateField(verbose_name='Relocation Date', default=date.today())
```

Table 'Hardware_Relocation' with values for example:

```
id hardware subdivision relocation_date

1 1 1   01.01.2009
2 1 2   01.01.2010
3 1 1   01.01.2011
4 1 3   01.01.2012
5 1 3   01.01.2013
6 1 3   01.01.2014
7 1 3   01.01.2015 # Now hardware 1 located in subdivision 3 because relocation_date is max
```

I would like to write a filter to find hardwares in subdivisions on today.

I'm trying to write a filter:

```
subdivision = Subdivision.objects.get(pk=1)
hardware_list = Hardware.objects.annotate(relocation__relocation_date=Max('relocation__relocation_date')).filter(relocation__subdivision = subdivision)
```

Now *hardware_list* contains *hardware* 1, but it is wrong (because now *hardware* 1 in *subdivision* 3).
*hardware_list* must be *None* in this example.

The following code works wrong (*hardware_list* contains hardware 1, for subdivision 1).

```
limit_date = datetime.datetime.now()
q1 = Hardware.objects.filter(relocation__subdivision=subdivision,  relocation__relocation_date__lte=limit_date)
q2 = q1.exclude(~Q(relocation__relocation_date__gt=F('relocation__relocation_date')), ~Q(relocation__subdivision=subdivision))
hardware_list = q2.distinct()
```

Maybe better use SQL?

Comment: Please clarify this: I would like to write a filter to find hardwares in subdivisions on today.

Comment: @Lorenzo Peña Hardwares moved from one subdivision to another. Each relocation has a date (field relocation_date in Hardware_Relocation).
I would like to get a list of hardware in specified subdivision on current moment. Subdivision 3 contains hardware 1 in example.

Comment: Isn't this enough? `Hardware.objects.filter(relocation__subdivision=target_subdivision, relocation__relocation_date=target_date).distinct()`

Comment: @Lorenzo Peña Not a target_date. It must be a maximum date for this hardware, not a specific (not today date, it may be a date in past).

Comment: So you want the inventory of a given subdivision in a point in time?

Comment: @Lorenzo Peña Yes, I would like to know, where is hardware located (in which subdivision?) now. The relocation_date must be maximum for this hardware.

Answer (score 1):

This might work...

```
from django.db.models import F, Q
Hardware.objects
    .filter(relocation__subdivision=target_subdivision, relocation__relocation_date__lte=limit_date)
    .exclude(~Q(relocation__subdivision=target_subdivision), relocation__relocation_date__gt=F('relocation__relocation_date'))
    .distinct()
```

The idea is, give me all hardware that have been relocated to target division before limit date, which DON'T have been relocated to other divisions after that.

Comment: If you are going to use SQL, you can query the max `relocation_date ` of a hardware prior to the target date and then stay with those whose max `relocation_date` point to the target subdivision.

Comment: @VadimKiselev please use the edit link to improve your question and add details, do not post code as comments.